# PHP dynamically bind mysqli_stmt_bind_param

Tags: php, prepared-statement

I'm pretty new in prepared statements but as I understand I need to dynamically bind parameters, but it doesn't work the way I do it, first I check how many "?" I'm going to need in my prepare statement by doing this(it can come with 5 different variants):

```
if(strlen($champion_skirtukai) == 1) $int_str_arrangement = "iis";
if(strlen($champion_skirtukai) == 2) $int_str_arrangement = "iiis";
if(strlen($champion_skirtukai) == 3) $int_str_arrangement = "iiiis";
if(strlen($champion_skirtukai) == 4) $int_str_arrangement = "iiiiis";
if(strlen($champion_skirtukai) == 5) $int_str_arrangement = "iiiiiis";
```

Next, I generate a part of my sql:

```
$filter_champ_arr = str_split($champion_skirtukai);
$sql_string = "";
$num_champ_arr = 0;
$this_var_is_for_bind_param = "";
foreach ($filter_champ_arr as &$value)
{
    if($num_champ_arr == 0) $sql_string .= "AND LENGTH(champion) - LENGTH(REPLACE(champion, '$', '')) =? ";
    else $sql_string .= "OR LENGTH(champion) - LENGTH(REPLACE(champion, '$', '')) =? ";
    $num_champ_arr++;
    $this_var_is_for_bind_param .= "$value,";
}
$this_var_is_for_bind_param = substr($this_var_is_for_bind_param, 0, -1);
```

And finally I do all the prepare statement stuff:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_conx, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $int_str_arrangement, $_POST['filter_by_date'], $this_var_is_for_bind_param, $_POST['filter_by_arrangement']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $single_id, $single_title, $single_description, $single_champion);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

So if my $champion_skirtukai = "134"(one of possibilities), then i'd get following values:

> $int_str_arrangement = "iiiis"
>
> $this_var_is_for_bind_param = "1,3,4"

And then I'll get an error:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in ... on line 42

And line 42 looks like this:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, $int_str_arrangement, $_POST['filter_by_date'], $this_var_is_for_bind_param, $_POST['filter_by_arrangement']);
```

So how should I deal with this? Everything works fine if length of $champion_skirtukai = 1...

Comment: another alternative would be something like `str_repeat('i', count($filter_champ_arr))`

Comment: Well that's a bit offtopic, all I need is an answer on how to solve this hard part :)

Comment: Still no answer, I've been trying to fix this for a couple of days already :|

Comment: Its a pain binding dynamic parameters using this API, consider also using an alternative which is PDO. if you really cant, you could use this way http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#104073

Comment: Okay, I'll try to learn how to it PDO way :)